# Querying for Validation Rules and Workflow Rules by criteria

Tags: workflow, query, metadata-api, validation, tooling-api

I'm trying to query for all Validation Rules and Workflow Rules that have a specific value in the criteria.

From [developer.salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_validationrule.htm), I see that I can query Validation Rule, but I need to filter the results by the errorConditionFormula, where it contains the specific text I'm looking for. I'm using VSCode and querying for Tooling API

SELECT ID, errorDisplayField, errorMessage, description, errorConditionFormula FROM ValidationRule
WHERE active = TRUE AND errorConditionFormula LIKE '%test%'

I also need to perform a similar query for Workflow Rules, but can't find the Tooling API equivalent of the criteria [formula](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm) (The formula field in the WorkflowRule table in that link).